# Estimates of entropy of functional spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, approximation-theory, entropy

Let $M^n$ be a compact $n$-dimensional manifold. For $k\geq 0$ let us denote by $C^k(M)$ the Banach space of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions, and $B_{C^k}$ denote the unit ball of it.

The image of $B_{C^1}$ in $C^0(M)$ is relatively compact by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Hence the entropy (covering) numbers 
$$N(\varepsilon):=\min\{N|\, \exists x_1,\dots,x_N\in B_{C^1} \mbox{ s.t. } B_{C^1}\subset \cup_{i=1}^N(x_i+\varepsilon B_{C^0}) \}$$
are finite.

**Question. What is the asymptotic behaviour of $N(\varepsilon)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ (in terms of the dimension of $M$ probably)?**

Similar question can be asked for the inclusion of Sobolev spaces
$$L^{k,p}(M)\to L^{l,p}(M),\, k>l,$$
which is compact (by the Kondrachov theorem).

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: Check the paper by Kolmogorov an Tihomirov *$\varepsilon$-entropy and $\varepsilon$-capacity of sets in functional spaces*, Uspehi. Mat. Nauk, 14(1956), t.2, 3-86.